# Custom indexing in Azure Cosmos Document DB doesn't work

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb

Ok, so the CosmosDb Collection has it's index policy set to consistent, automatic, has the default hash and range indexes **AND** we added a path to our own timestamp properties in order to sort by them.

I know the paths are correct, since I'm not able to order by them UNLESS I have them set. But:

When sorting by Cosmos built-in property **_ts** - the cost for an OrderBy query is like **20 RU/s**. That's great.
Now, when sorting by our **OWN** timestamp columns *(we have two where one is a string timestamp, and the other is Unixbased number just as the built-in **_ts** column*. 
This query costs **400 RU/s !???**

Putting the new indexing rules enable us to query and order it, but the *RUs* are insane. Why is this and how do we address it?

*I know that you couldn't change the indexing policy Ad Hoc earlier, but this has been addressed according to Microsoft.*

**EDIT:** It is a simple collection, no partitioning is configured, and the query runs against this only collection, selects only one document (top 1).

`SELECT top 1 * FROM c WHERE c.AllCompleted = true ORDER BY c.EndFetchDateTimeUtcUnix DESC`
vs

`SELECT top 1 * FROM c WHERE c.AllCompleted = true ORDER BY c._ts DESC`

The Index looking like this: 

    `{
      "indexingMode": "consistent",
      "automatic": true,
      "includedPaths": [
        {
          "path": "/",
          "indexes": [
            {
              "kind": "Hash",
              "dataType": "Number",
              "precision": 3
            },
            {
              "kind": "Hash",
              "dataType": "String",
              "precision": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "path": "/EndFetchDateTimeUtcUnix/?",
          "indexes": [
            {
              "kind": "Range",
              "dataType": "Number",
              "precision": -1
            },
            {
              "kind": "Hash",
              "dataType": "String",
              "precision": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "excludedPaths": []
    }`

Comment: Can you include additional information including how many docs are returned from your custom query vs the order by _ts and whether or not this query is confined to a single partition?

Comment: Sure, it's only one. Edited the post above with the queries and the index.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the case here that you're hitting index collision (multiple values map to the same index term).

To minimize the chances of collisions, and if the order-by item has known min/max values, you could add a filter on the order-by item to narrow down the range of index terms retrieved.

For instance,

SELECT * 
FROM c 
WHWE **c.DateTime BETWEEN '2000-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z' AND '3000-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z'**
ORDER BY c.DateTime

Similarly you could apply the same technique to the numeric timestamp.

Comment: But the precision is set to -1 (maximum) for a number. See above edited post.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you investigate what does DocumentDB is spending it's effort on. Turn to the [Query execution metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics) header for clues.

Comment: Would appreciate explanation on the delete-vote. The execution metrics is the best way for the OP to investigate and understand WHY he is experiencing this difference. If not, educate me.